# IIS: More requests than it can handle, server dead. How to fix it?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, iis, iis-7

So I have this IIS 7 web server on Windows Server 2008 R2 (it runs ColdFusion 10 as well, but that's not important for this purpose). It runs pretty solid, but I didn't have a lot of traffic anyway.

A few hours ago I started getting a steady 2-3k page views per minute, directed at a certain, blank page. It is more or less supposed to be that way, not a DDOS attempt or anything, but it completely shuts down the server.

I tried setting up a request restriction for the site in question, but that didn't help, it seems like the presence of a lot of requests alone are enough to kill the server.

While I'm interested in getting the server to be able to deal with a lot of requests (if you have some insight in how to do that, that's great), the most important thing right now is a quick fix, i.e. somehow making my IIS "immune" to all these page requests.

Any idea? Thanks in advance!

Comment: When you say "blank page," do you mean there's a static html page (with a html or htm file extension) that says `<html><head></head><body></body></html>` or equivalent, or is there any server-side processing (aspx, cfm) going on?

Comment: Actually it's a CFM page. After I saw the server couldn't handle the load, I deleted it, so it should just return a 404. Which it does, at least at those times where a request comes through. Most requests end with a 503 status code.

Comment: I think your bottleneck is the server-side processing.  I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish with the 2-3K hits a minute, but if it's a blank page, consider serving up a .htm or .html in order to bypass Cold Fusion altogether.  If you can't, well.  Consider putting valid html content in the blank file, in case the Cold Fusion engine just thinks it's missing directives or something.  Potentially random sounding question:  what kind of disks are in this box?

Comment: The requests will continue to be directed at this specific .cfm URL, I could rewrite it to open a html file so ColdFusion doesn't get in the way. But are you sure this can be the case here? The file is deleted AND I have an IIS "request restriction" to block the request before it is even analyzed.

About the disks, I don't know, it's a commercially rented server, so it's not old and rusty but probably not super high end either.

Comment: No, I'm not sure.  I'd check with your host and ask about memory and cpu, sure, but especially disk IO.  The more I think about it, I'm actually starting to suspect that you've thrown a disk or something.

Comment: Server seems to have an SSD raid setup, which one exactly, can't tell. By "thrown a disk" you mean hardware issues? Because the problems started exactly at the same time the flood of requests started...

Appreciate your help though!

Comment: Yeah, a bad disk in RAID 5 will show up when you have a heavy read load and lock up the server.

Answer (score 1):

If it ain't a ddos attack it looks like one.

What I'd do here is setup a reverse proxy using IIS AAR in front of this. Typically this would just pass requests to the back-end server which is now running at an odd, non-passed-through-the-firewall port. Then for the specific page I would setup a rule on the proxy to just return bad request. This scales very well, at least until you run out of bandwidth on your network port.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to say from the information you've provided--I'd want to see if anything interesting appeared in your IIS logs and event viewer, and get more information on the hardware--but my shot in the dark is, as I said above, "thrown disk."  A bad disk in RAID 5 will show up when you have a heavy read load and lock up the server.  (I've had an entire college "DOSed" when the LDAP server was backed up--the admin of that box didn't realize one of his disks had died.  People called me rather than him at home because my service was dependent on his.)

You said in the comments that your server was running on SSD RAID.  SSDs do unpredictably die, so it might be worth following up on that.  A healthy SSD RAID--and a healthy server--should be able to handle the load you mentioned.